# Link Taxonomy with Node via Feeds, Entity Reference and Views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds, entities

I have a JSON feed that basically describes various objects described in an **object** lets say for example different cars.
In the feed, there is an **object_type** attribute that is just a number. Those numbers refer to different car brands which are described in a **list** object.

Thus the JSON Path is similar to:

```
$.object.object_type
$.list.id
$.list.name
// Where if 'object_type' == 'id', then display: 'name'
```

I've created 2 Feed Importers using JSONPath and was able to add my '**objects**' (cars) to a custom node item (car_item) as well as to add my '**list**' (of car brands) to a taxonomy vocabulary (brand_vocab). However I don't seem to be able to actually 'link/relate' them together.

For the brand_vocab, I have added an Entity Reference field (field_brand_id) and set the Target Type to be a Taxonomy Term (using Mode simple).
For my Feed Importer for **car_item**'s, I`ve added the mapping for the json query to link to field_brand_id and set it to id for the query.

In fact, the taxonomy terms don't contain the filled in results for the id even though when I debug the Importer it all works fine.

Ideally I want my custom view to have a drop-down filter of the taxonomy terms (car brands) for the different custom nodes (car items). I have the view set-up, with the taxonomy vocob (brand_vocab) as a drop-down, just the filter doesn't work as the link between the node and taxonomy isn't working yet.

---

UPDATE: 10/01/2012

Ok so at the moment I have:

Feed Importer

- Object (Cars)

  - Set as Custom content Type: Cars
  - Mapping for: name
  - Mapping for: brand
- Object Type (Car Brands)

  - Set as Tax Term: object_type
  - Mapping for Term Name: name
  - Mapping for Term GUID: guid

Content Type

- Cars

  - name
  - brand = Entity Reference
  - Target Type: Taxonomy Term - object_type

Now viewing the actual node for the Cars - I have the right Car Brand showing up as name and not the 'id' which is what I want.

However, the taxonomy term is not actually added to the Content type.

That and I have 2 Entity References that I need to use (Object Type and Category Type), however the content type shows both as the same term! So it seems to be that Entity Reference just checks the ID and then displays that and not the ID and Vocabulary (since I selected one ER to be for 1 Vocab bundle, and the other to be for another Vocab bundle).

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I decided to scrap the Taxonomy Vocabulary and use new Content Types instead.

Haven't been able to figure out a good way to link multiple Taxonomy Vocabularies to Content Types via importing in Feeds and using Entity Reference with Views.